# How to pass "?" symbol as table alias name?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have to pass question mark symbol(?) as table alias name in query from C# code to oracle database. It is giving me exception:

> Number of Parameters supplied (0) does not match the number of Placeholders (2) in the SQL Statement.

It is due to question mark symbol. Please suggest a way to overcome this solution. 
Similar problem is coming in inserting the data from c# code.

Example:

```
SELECT SYSDATE AS "IS NEWYEAR ?" FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Please don't use such characters in a column name...

Comment: Request you to please share the exact query with us.

Comment: First of all if you want the date, you can use C# to get it and you don't have to use SQL. Secondly an actual example would help as I don't think the current example would result in the same error

Comment: Actual Query is dynamic query.Created in C# Code. The Table is required with "?" as there is some business requirement.

Comment: @SahilGupta I doubt any business requirement specifies temporary table column names. If the customer wants a field with this *caption*, read the data using a sensible name then put the result in the proper field. Using the display text as a column name is a very bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine here, escaping the `"` in C#:

```
using (OracleConnection oc = new OracleConnection("..."))
{
    oc.Open();

    OracleCommand cm = oc.CreateCommand();
    cm.CommandText = "SELECT SYSDATE AS \"IS NEWYEAR ?\" FROM DUAL";

    object o = cm.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, When i am seeing the query in Text mode, there is no escape sequence but when i went to change it is showing escape sequence is already there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The query generated using C# code, already contains escape character before alias name. So, i think i am not going to provide the escape sequence again.Still the same error persists.

Comment: @SahilGupta: Does it work with the above code? If so, it is an issue in the string formatting. Can you show the query string?

Comment: The query goes like this.Select Distinct 'Y' "PRICE CODE IN MAXIMIS?"
 FROM [tableName]. I am using aics method to get dataset.

Comment: Also see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm): _6.
Nonquoted identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (\_), dollar sign ($), and pound sign (#). .. Oracle strongly discourages you from using $ and # in nonquoted identifiers.

Quoted identifiers can contain any characters and punctuations marks as well as spaces. However, neither quoted nor nonquoted identifiers can contain double quotation marks or the null character (\0)._ These rules notwithstanding having a `?` in a name is madness!

Comment: @SahilGupta: What is `aics`? Can you also tell what provider you are using?

Comment: Then I guess the problem is there, since the default `OracleConnection` works fine with this query.

Comment: Yaah, thanks for help. It is working with default oracleconnection.

Comment: @SahilGupta: Report a bug at the company providing that provider.